# change the font of a keyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, keyboard

I am working on a custom keyboard in Swift 2. I would use a different font for all the label, buttons and text. Is it possible to set a font's value once for all the code?
I am working with
`class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for my previous answer, try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setFontFamily("FagoOfficeSans-Regular", forView: self.view!, andSubViews: true)
}




func setFontFamily(fontFamily: String, forView view: UIView, andSubViews isSubViews: Bool) {

    if view.isKindOfClass(UILabel){
        let lbl: UILabel = view as! UILabel
        lbl.font = UIFont(name: fontFamily, size: lbl.font.pointSize)
    }
    if view.isKindOfClass(UIButton){
        let lbl: UIButton = view as! UIButton
        lbl.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: fontFamily, size: 12)!
    }

    if view.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
        let lbl: UITextField = view as! UITextField
        lbl.font = UIFont(name: fontFamily, size: 12)

    }

    if isSubViews {
        for sview: UIView in view.subviews {
            self.setFontFamily(fontFamily, forView: sview, andSubViews: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. Where should I place this? Like  UIInputViewController { AnyUIView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: yourSize) }

Comment: try in viewDidLoad()

Comment: I've tried like this:  override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        UIInputViewController.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "font name", size: font size)} } but it doesn't work...

Comment: @LordNexprex try my new answer. hope this helps.

Comment: you can substitute the UILabel with any other class you are working with btw.

Comment: Well it didn't worked... I don't know why...  for example changing the class to UIButton gives me an error....

Comment: it would be different for UIButton (slightly), let me update the class for you. will edit the answer in a bit.

Comment: @LordNexprex, please accept answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Just one more thing... I also need it with the UITextInput class, which is the one with I've got the most difficulties...

Comment: what exactly do you need to do with UITextInput? @LordNexprex

Comment: @LordNexprex, I added what it would be for a textfield. not sure what else you would need.

Comment: I would change the font of my UITextInput, which  now is: override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) { 
        let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy }

Comment: @LordNexprex, can you share more code? I would be interested in seeing your entire controller. perhaps I can help you better.

Comment: @LordNexprex, I'm afraid that is all you can change (the label, the button text, and the textfield texts). Otherwise, there is no fonts to change.